# Dynamic content inside CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a RecyclerView which holds CardView, where I want to display data. In case of a variable is missing, I am setting the visibility of that Layout as Gone.

When I land on the cardview everything seems look ok, but when I scroll up and down, even existing Layouts are hidden from upper Cards.

Any idea what causes it, and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, please post the source code. This is basically impossible to diagnose without it. However that won't stop me from taking a shot ;)

If you have some logic that sets the layout visibility to GONE, then do you also have logic that sets the visibility to VISIBLE?

If not then my guess is that you first set the view to GONE, then when the view goes off screen it gets recycled and the next time you use the recycled view the visibility is still set to GONE.

Comment: i figured that out, and yes it is the right answer. However regarding code, due to client sensitivity it is sometimes difficult to post the code, or screen shot, hope you understand.